# Iterate through files

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm trying to adapt someone's code for my (Windows 7) purposes. His is unfortunately UNIX specific. He does

```
dir_ = pathlib.PosixPath(str(somePathVariable))
os.chdir(str(dir_))
for pth in dir_:        
    # some operations here
```

Running this, I got (not surprisingly)

```
NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system
```

I looked into the documentation for `pathlib` and thought yeah, I should just be able to change `PosixPath` to `Path` and I would be fine. Well, then `dir_` generates a `WindowsPath` object. So far, so good. However, I get

```
TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not iterable
```

`pathlib` is at version 1.0, what am I missing? The purpose is to iterate through files in the specific directory. Googling this second error gave *0* hits.

Remark: Could not use `pathlib` as a tag, hence I put it into the title.

**Update**

I have Python 2.7.3 and  pathlib 1.0

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I guess you should use [`Path.iterdir()`](https://pathlib.readthedocs.org/en/pep428/#pathlib.Path.iterdir).

```
for pth in dir_.iterdir():

    #Do your stuff here
```

Comment: `for path in Path(".").glob("*.csv"): print(path)` keeps only specific file extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
for pth in dir_.iterdir():
```

Related documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir

Answer (score 1):

Use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module instead, which works same on both platforms:

```
import glob
for item in glob.glob('/your/path/*')  # use any mask suitable for you
   print item # prints full file path
```

Comment: You can use the `.glob()` method on Path objects; no need to switch back to the legacy functions.

Comment: In the past, I found the `glob.glob()` on Windows returns a list of filenames in lexical order, while on Linux order is not guaranteed. So when I ported code from Win to Linux, I had to sort the results from `glob.glob()` to have consistent behavior. I don't know if `Path.glob` is similar, but it is worth checking.

Answer (score 1):

```
dir_ = pathlib.Path(str(somePathVariable))
os.chdir(str(dir_))
for pth in dir_:        
    # some operations here
```

Now your code will work on both platforms. You are specifing de type of path... if you want it to be cross-platform you have to use "Path" not "PosixPath"

Answer (score 0):

**Important to know:**
Every time you encounter an `object is not iterable` error, you must remember that the system also performs an iteration on a string,
For example:

```
import yagmail

def send_email(to: list, subject: str, content: list, attachments=None):
    yagmail.SMTP(from_user_name, password)\
    .send(to=to, subject=subject, contents=content, attachments=attachments)
```

This function is also the contents of the email and the attachment must be in the list! (even if there is only one file).

**In conclusion:** Always try to insert the string into the list that can save a lot of problems.